# Palindromic Partition

Tags: python, recursion

Given a string, a partitioning of the string is a palindrome partitioning if every substring of the partition is a palindrome. For example, “aba|b|bbabb|a|b|aba” is a palindrome partitioning of “ababbbabbababa”. Determine the fewest cuts needed for palindrome partitioning of a given string. For example, minimum 3 cuts are needed for “ababbbabbababa”. The three cuts are “a|babbbab|b|ababa”. If a string is palindrome, then minimum 0 cuts are needed. If a string of length n containing all different characters, then minimum n-1 cuts are needed.

I am using recursive method instead of using dynamic programming. But I am not able to store minimum that I get at every stage on partitioning from ith position.

```
def minCut(A):
    minCut.res = float('inf')
    j = 0
    if A[:] == A[::-1]:
        print(0)
    else:
        recur(A, len(A))
        print(minCut.res)


def recur(A, n):
    if(len(A) <= 1):
        return 0
    if(A[:] == A[::-1]):
        return 0

    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        track = 1 + recur(A[0:i+1], len(A)) + recur(A[i+1:], len(A))
        if n == len(A):
            minCut.res = min(minCut.res, track)

    return track

minCut('ababbbabbababa')
```

expected result - 3

actual result - 6

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from `if (A[:] == A[::-1]): return 0`?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question, its not entirely clear what you are asking. Additionally I think you should approach the problem by trying to find the largest palindrome first, then partitioning the rest.

Comment: @ChrisSullivan finding local maxima might not give me global minima i.e. finding the largest palindrome first might not always give me minimum partitition required